# Subsetting and recombine rows of dataframes in a list

Tags: r, list

I'm working with a big dataset containing information of cows movement (coordinates) which i have separated into multiple matrices in a list. Each matrix contains the distance between each cow every 15 min.

At the moment i want to separate and recombine the matrices so i have a matrix of each individual and it's distances through the whole periode.

This is a few examples of what I'm working with:

```r
Results[["2023-08-15 00:01:00"]] <- data.frame(
 Cow1 = c(NA, 65, 2, 7),
 Cow2 = c(65, NA, 16, 84),
 Cow3 = c(2, 16, NA, 8),
 Cow4 = c(7, 84, 8, NA))

Results[["2023-08-15 00:16:00"]] <- data.frame(
 Cow1 = c(NA, 65, 2, 7),
 Cow2 = c(65, NA, 16, 84),
 Cow3 = c(2, 16, NA, 8),
 Cow4 = c(7, 84, 8, NA))
```

and what i want is the data to look like is something like this:

```r
Results[["Cow1"]] <- data.frame(
 "2023-08-15 00:01:00" = c(NA, 65, 2, 7),
 "2023-08-15 00:16:00" = c(NA, 65, 2, 7)
)
```

I'm still quite a beginner so i have no idea how to do this of how to figure it out. But i have tried this:

```r
Results_Cows <- tapply(result, names(result), dplyr::bind_rows)
```

EDIT:
Here is the results in a list

```r
"2023-08-15 00:01:00" <- data.frame(
  Cow1 = c(NA, 65, 2, 7),
  Cow2 = c(65, NA, 16, 84),
  Cow3 = c(2, 16, NA, 8),
  Cow4 = c(7, 84, 8, NA))

"2023-08-15 00:16:00" <- data.frame(
  Cow1 = c(NA, 65, 2, 7),
  Cow2 = c(65, NA, 16, 84),
  Cow3 = c(2, 16, NA, 8),
  Cow4 = c(7, 84, 8, NA))

Results <- list("2023-08-15 00:01:00", "2023-08-15 00:16:00")
```

Comment: Although your desired output is clear to me, I do not have `Results`. Please add to make it a reproducible Q.

Comment: I have added it now

Comment: Run your example (EDIT) in a fresh R session. And check `Results`. "2023-08-15 00:01:00" and "2023-08-15 00:16:00"  are two characters in `Results`, there are no data frames in `Results`. You could change to Results <- list(`2023-08-15 00:01:00`, ...), where you use (backtick) quotes. But in this case `names(Results)` returns `NULL`. What does `names(your_real_data_list)` return?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two alternative approaches.

#### `base` R approach

Iterate over the unique cows and extract each relevant cow for that date in `results`.

```r
(cows <- unique(unlist(lapply(results, names))))
# [1] "Cow1" "Cow2" "Cow3" "Cow4"
lapply(cows, \(cow) {
    lapply(results, \(date) {
        vals <- date[[cow]]
        if (is.null(vals)) vals <- rep(NA_real_, nrow(date))
        vals
    })
}) |> setNames(cows)
```

Output (piped to `jsonlite::toJSON(pretty = TRUE)`, as R prints nested lists in a horrible format).

```r
{
  "Cow1": {
    "2023-08-15 00:01:00": ["NA", 65, 2, 7],
    "2023-08-15 00:16:00": ["NA", 65, 2, 7]
  },
  "Cow2": {
    "2023-08-15 00:01:00": [65, "NA", 16, 84],
    "2023-08-15 00:16:00": [65, "NA", 16, 84]
  },
  "Cow3": {
    "2023-08-15 00:01:00": [2, 16, "NA", 8],
    "2023-08-15 00:16:00": [2, 16, "NA", 8]
  },
  "Cow4": {
    "2023-08-15 00:01:00": [7, 84, 8, "NA"],
    "2023-08-15 00:16:00": [7, 84, 8, "NA"]
  }
}
```

#### `dplyr` approach

First [`bind_rows()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind_rows.html) your original list to allow you to [`pivot_longer()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) your data. Then [`split()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html) by name, and `split()` again by date.

```r
library(dplyr)
results |>
    bind_rows(.id = "date") |>
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-date) |>
    split(~name) |>
    lapply(\(df)
        lapply(
            split(df, ~date),
            \(x) x$value
        )
    )
```

Output the same as above.

##### Input data

```r
results <- list(`2023-08-15 00:01:00` = structure(list(Cow1 = c(NA, 65, 
2, 7), Cow2 = c(65, NA, 16, 84), Cow3 = c(2, 16, NA, 8), Cow4 = c(7, 
84, 8, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)), `2023-08-15 00:16:00` = structure(list(
    Cow1 = c(NA, 65, 2, 7), Cow2 = c(65, NA, 16, 84), Cow3 = c(2, 
    16, NA, 8), Cow4 = c(7, 84, 8, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much the dplyr approach worked perfectly

Comment: @SiaLemons out of interest did the first approach not work? I'm guessing perhaps your real data is slightly different - perhaps different cows in each data frame?

Comment: Yes I'm working with data from a GPS tracker which sometimes loses connection meaning not every dataframe have the same amount of individuals. Both approaches seems to work fine however the base R returned the missing data as a NULL while dplyr returned a list of NA which seems (to me as a beginner) like a better result for my further analysis

Comment: @SiaLemons I agree `NA` is better. I have amended the first answer to be able to handle cases where some names are missing by checking if the result is `NULL` and replacing with `NA`.

Comment: Hmmm it turns out i still have some troubles. The second approach returns the data in a desirable way however the rows are of different lengths so I'm not able to combine them into dataframes. The first approach returns only a single value for each time interval. All of this i properly a problem with how i split the data earlier in the code.

Comment: @SiaLemons this is not a good approach if you want to end up with a data frame. Probably what you want can be achieved by pivoting from wide to long and back again. I would suggest asking a different question with some sample input (before it is split) and final expected output.

Comment: @SiaLemons I see you have un-accepted this answer. I've updated the first answer so that it returns the same number of values for each time period if `NA`. However I still recommend asking another question.